# How to manipulate iptables rules from the web script

Tags: c, linux, apache, cgi

I have a linux box with web serverthe has 2 running services:

1. web proxy (listens ports 80, 443)
2. apache (listens port 8080)

The users for proxy can register through web interface. I must give access to proxy only to the registered clients with certain IPs. Proxy is a handwritten script, and I have to use iptables to block the access. I wrote the following rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -s <valid IP 1> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -s <valid IP 2> -j ACCEPT
...
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -s <valid IP n> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DROP
```

It works. But when a new user is added through web interface, Apache launches a script as a non-root user. And I have to run `iptables` as root.

[I can't set suid bit for a program, written in a scripting language](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/27689), so I created a C program `updater.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int result = system("iptables -L");
    printf("\nresult=%i", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled it:

```
# gcc -o updater ./updater.c
# chmod +s ./updater
```

When I run it as a non-priviledged user in shell it works correctly: prints all the iptables rules.

When I run it from the web, calling the program inside a shell script, it doesn't print anything. Despite the fact, that when I tried to create a file inside this C program, it was created with owner=root. `system("ls -l");` also works - it prints the directory listing.

How can I manipulate iptables rules from the web script?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that `iptables` is not on the `PATH` given to your web-server-launched process. The right solution would include not using `system()` at all but at a minimum, provide the full path to the executable, not just the name of it.

Comment: @mah Yeah, it was the path to iptables. After changing it to `/sbin/iptables` it worked. Can you put it as an answer?

Comment: glad it helped. Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `system("iptables -L");` you may or may not be able to find `iptables`, depending on your `PATH` environment variable. You should prepend the path to where the binary is so that you know it will be found:

```
int result = system("/sbin/iptables -L");
```